Transfer the Development files to another Host (colleague / Person)
I have created the python code for the local chatbot. I, now, want to transfer the entire code (with all dependencies) to the another person for the server deployment. Therefore, I have decided to use the docker container. I have created the Dockerfile which has the information about all dependencies.
Since the local chatbot is using the services of Ollama, I have used the Ollama Image and then mentioned it as a one service in Docker-compose.yml file apart from the Dockerfile. Docker-compose.yml has the information also of the chatbot.
Now my question is: How can I transfer entire development files (main.py, Dockerfile and docker.compose.yml) to another colleague so that they can run without any external installation of any dependencies?
Is there any possibility to upload (or Push) Dockerfile and docker-compose.yml file (both) to the Dockerhub?

If you only wish to share development files, you should be able to zip the relevant files and send it over. Assuming they have a development environment setup, they should be able to get it to work.
A more standard approach would be to use a source control software like Git to manage your project in a remote repository and then share that repository with your colleague. This also makes it easy to collaborate with each other. See: https://anidiots.guide/other-guides/using-git-to-share-and-update-code/
In addition to the above, if you do not want your colleague to have to setup python, install dependencies, etc. you should be able to use something like VS Code Dev Containers. This is a way to package the entire development into a container. See this for an example: https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-remote-try-python
Lastly, if all you want is to let your colleague run the code, you can push your docker image to a container registry (like Docker Hub, GitHub Container Registry, etc.) and have your colleague pull the image.
If this is supposed to be used by a non-technical user, the simplest way would be to host your code somewhere and share a link with your colleague.
